# when I use the map-reduce of mongodb, why does it nest?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I insert into mongo with the code:

```
for (var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
db.test.insert({ "name" : "user"+i, "age":i%17 , "created_at" : new Date() });
}
```

and the map function is

```
var m = function(){ emit(this.age,this.name); }
```

the reduce function is

```
var r=function(key,values){ var ret={age:key,names:values}; return ret;}
```

But, when I run the code

```
db.runCommand({mapreduce:"test",map:m,reduce:r,     out:"t_age_names"} )
```

I get 17 json and everyone is like

> { "_id" : 8, "value" : { "age" : 8, "names" : [ { "age" : 8, "names" :
>   [ { "age" : 8, "names" : [ "user8", "user25", "user42", "user59",
>   "user76", "user93", "user110", "user127", "user144", "user161",
>   "user178", "user195" ] }, "user212", "user229", "user246", "user263",
>   "user280", "user297", "user314", "user331", "user348", "user365",
>   "user382", "user399" ] }, { "age" : 8, "names" : [ { "age" : 8,
>   "names" : [ "user416", "user433", "user450", "user467", "user484",
>   "user501", "user518", "user535", "user552", "user569", "user586" ] },
>   "user603", "user620", "user637", "user654", "user671", "user688",
>   "user705", "user722", "user739", "user756", "user773", "user790" ] },
>   { "age" : 8, "names" : [ "user807", "user824", "user841", "user858",
>   "user875", "user892", "user909", "user926", "user943", "user960",
>   "user977", "user994" ] } ] } }

Why does it nest?

Why does it nest?
And the length of every array is 12, it seems like to be caused by `emit` function, is it?

Comment: Are you grouping names by age? Looks like it can be done more efficiently with the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: I just want to study the map-reduce of mongodb and test it. Of course, the aggregation pipeline would be more efficiently

Answer (score 0):

Your `reduce` violates [at least] one of [the requirements](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce-reduce-cmd):

> the type of the return object must be **identical** to the type of the value emitted by the `map` function.

So either change what `reduce` outputs, or what `map` does.

Comment: @cong: not sure what you mean by that. But yes, your reduce, among other things, must be idempotent.